# JAXB marshaling and unmarshaling

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

While going through the XML marshaling and unmarshaling techniques in `JAVA`, I came across this doubt,Why we do we have `JAXB` related packages in other apis like `jakarta-xml-bind-api` and `jaxb-api`, when we already have it in the `jdk`?

Comment: JAXB is not part of the JDK since Java 9

Answer (score -1):

```
//This method convert object to Xml     
public void testObjectToXml() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(product, new File("product.xml"));
            marshaller.marshal(product, System.out);
        }
//This method convert xml to object    
private static Bookstore convertXMLToObject() {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class);
            Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Bookstore bookstore = (Bookstore) un.unmarshal(new File(BOOKSTORE_XML));
            List < Book > list = bookstore.getBooksList();
            for (Book book: list) {
                System.out.println("Book: " + book.getName() + " from " + book.getAuthor());
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: That's not my question. My question is why is there the same class JAXBContext in other third party apis,when we already have it in jdk